# Shell: Fork (daemonize) a subshell such that it survives the death of its tmux session

Tags: shell, fork, zsh, daemon, tmux

I am trying to fork a subshell that survives the termination of the tmux session it was created on. I have tried a double fork strategy:

```
insubshell-eval () {
    local cmd="$@"
    (
        eval "$cmd"
    )
}
gquote () {
    # quotes the arguments
    print -r -- "${(q+@)@}"
}
awaysh1 () {
    local cmd="$(gquote "$@") & ; disown "
    setopt LOCAL_OPTIONS NO_NOTIFY NO_MONITOR
    insubshell-eval "$cmd" &
     &> /dev/null < /dev/null || return $?
    disown &> /dev/null || true
}
awaysh-exit () {
    awaysh1 "$@"
    exit 0
}
awaysh-doublefork () {
    awaysh1 awaysh-exit "$@"
}
```

I then play some audio using the above to check when the process is terminated:

```
tmux kill-ses -t t1 ; tmux new-session -d -s t1 zsh -c "awaysh-doublefork play '/x/y.ogg'"
```

This command has race conditions (I don't know why) and sometimes plays the file correctly and more often doesn't play anything.

The only thing that comes to my mind is that the double-forked process still shares its process group ID with the original process, and is thus signaled to oblivion by tmux. But how do I change this process ID?

PS: I can't use `nohup`. I want the solution to be in pure `zsh`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `nohup` to have a process continue running after the shell that spawned it has died. It must be a process, not a subshell.

```sh
$ man nohup
```

Quick example of how to use:

```sh
$ nohup program argument &
```

Comment: `PS: I can't use nohup. I want the solution to be in pure zsh.` in the question.

Comment: `Nohup` is not part of bash, it is a separate program and has been part of *nix (UNIX, Linux and friends) for decades, like `grep` and `sed`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup

Comment: I know that. I do not want to use unix binaries. The reason is that the `program` is itself a zsh function, and no, I can't go and make that function execute using `zsh -c` for reasons.

Comment: That is bizarre.